# Uploaded site to IIS, cannot find controller resource (error 500). Works locally using iisexpress

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8

Been doing lots of testing and eventually got everything working in Visual Studio using iisexpress. I've deployed it into IIS via a web package.zip and now my function has stopped working. Any thoughts? Event viewer isn't reporting anything.

I click the button to call the ajax - the GET looks like it is properly formulated but it can't find something - I'm guessing the 'GetData' method. Do I need to change the URL.Action in the project before deploying? (Tried with and without content-type, hence the comment tags)

Ajax call

```
<script>
$("#button").click(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var uquery = $('#HospitalID').val();
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetData", "oncologyPatients")';
    //alert(uquery); //ENABLE FOR ERROR CHECKING OF VARIABLE
    var data = { value: uquery }
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: url,
        data: data,
        type: 'GET',
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

        success: function (data)
        {
            $('#HospitalID').val(data.HID);
            $('#NHS_No_').val(data.NHS);
            $('#Forename').val(data.Fname);
            $('#Surname').val(data.Sname);
            $('#DOB').val(data.DOB);
        },

        error: function (xhr, status, error)
        {
            alert(status);
            alert(error);
            var err = xhr.responseText;
            alert(err);

        }
    });
});
```

Click the button and locally it finds the 'GetData' in the controller and works fine. However, it throws a very generic error when running on IIS 8.5/Server 2012 R2 and I have to go into the dev. tools of Chrome to get something meaningful which is:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
http://siteuat.local.com/oncologyPatients/GetData?value=11111111
```

Any ideas, I'm leaning towards absolute URL but it looks as though the route is correct.

All other functions are fine - it's basically just this one call that is having problems.

Comment: The route is correct. 500 means, there is an uncaught exception in your GetData action. Attach to it with the debugger and see what's throwing it.

Comment: Thanks, figured it out after posting. Sod's law........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out a few minutes after posting - grrr. It was working locally because my user account had permissions to make a TrustedConnection to the database (which I didn't need).

My sqlConnection looked like this:

```
SqlConnection DWLKup = new SqlConnection("user id=user;" +
                       "password= password;server=Server\\Instance;" +
                       "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                       "database=db1; ");
```

I removed the

```
"Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
```

And it's all working now :)